# Inserir num ficheiro CSV

Tags: php, csv

Queria inserir num ficheiro CSV, os dados da tabela (SQLite). Faço uma consulta antes, e quero inserir o resultado dessa consulta no ficheiro CSV. Existe no PHP a função `fputcsv`. Consigo criar o ficheiro mas queria inserir. Aqui está o código:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$nombre;$i++){
        $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE $selectoption='$search' AND id=$i";    
        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();//

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[nom]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[prenom]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[fonction]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[societe]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[mobile]</td>";
            echo "<td>$affiche[mail]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

    $fp = fopen($search.".csv", 'w');

        fputcsv($fp, $list);
    fclose($fp);
    echo "ficheiro csv criado";
}
```

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo/1911#1911

Answer (score 1):

Não falta guardares os dados no $list?

```php
$list = array();
for ($i=0; $i<=$nombre;$i++){
        ...
        $list[] = $affiche;
        ...
    }

    $fp = fopen($search.".csv", 'w');

        fputcsv($fp, $list);
    fclose($fp);
    echo "ficheiro csv criado";
}
```

Comment: certo mas nao mostra nada no ficheiro.

Comment: Faz um print_r($list) para ver que dados lá estão antes de escrever no ficheiro.

Comment: Sim estao, da erro no linha do fputcsv. Array to string conversion

Comment: Mas qual é o conteúdo do teu $list? Faz um print para ver o que tem senão é difícil ajudar.